# How to detrend exponential time series in R?

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I am on my early stages of learning detrending. In R, when I see a linear trend, I use diff() function. Which, if I had the time series in a sheet of paper, I see it like "flipping the paper".

I checked `?diff` hoping for a parameter, but there isn't one... is there an R function to achieve detrending for an exponential trend?

Answer (score 1):

For an exponential trend, you usually want to take a logarithm to make it an additive trend, and then apply diff, so you should be able to just use diff(log(